# Viewing Windows Firewall settings from the command line and a GUI

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-firewall

Is it possible to view Windows firewall settings from the command line?

In addition how can I check the advanced Windows Firewall settings in a GUI?

Answer (score 17):

To view the Windows Firewall settings from the command line, type:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall
```

This will open a menu with different settings, including advanced settings (like setting rules).

[image: Windows Firewall settings in command-line]

[More information about Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall Commands (Windows Server online library).](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

powershell (windows 10):

```
get-netfirewallrule -all
get-netfirewallrule -policystore configurableservicestore -all
```

Not sure how to see the rules whose names start with "@" in the gui.  Netsh can't view alternate policystores, or view firewall rules by owner like powershell can.

Answer (score 8):

There's usually a shortcut somewhere in the Admin/System Tools folder of your Start Menu that will access Windows Firewall with the Advanced Security GUI.

Alternatively you can type `wf.msc` in an administrative Command Prompt.

The command `netsh advfirewall` (or `netsh firewall` in Windows XP) will let you view/work with firewall settings at the command line.