# Show Windows Firewall rules for an application in cli

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-firewall

Say, in Windows Firewall GUI I have this - four rules for `nc.exe` (`netcat`), two for private networks (one TCP, one UDP), and two for public networks (one TCP, one UDP):

[image: windows firewall screenshot]

How can I dump these four rules, related to `nc.exe`, on the command line?

via [Viewing Windows Firewall settings from the command line and a GUI](https://superuser.com/questions/468475/viewing-windows-firewall-settings-from-the-command-line-and-a-gui) , found out about `netsh`, and tried:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all profile=any type=static
```

... and it dumps a ton of data, just not anything with `nc.exe` in it.

So, how can I get/dump/show/print all rules (inbound) related to a program in Windows 10 Firewall on the command line?